# Python unit tests: type checking custom class type

Tags: python, unit-testing, types, sqlalchemy

I'm writing unit tests as I develop a program. I'm using SQLAlchemy for database processes, so I have a few functions like this:

```
def create_sqla_engine():
    """ Create and return the SQLA engine """
    mysql_uri = os.environ.get('MYSQL_CONNECTION_URI')
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(mysql_uri)
    return engine
```

If I do `print(type(engine))` I can see that the type is `<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>`

...so I want to test if this function works by checking if the type is correct (assuming the type will be `None` if the `create_engine` call fails...)

This code is in `unittests.py`:

```
class TestDatabase(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_database_create_merkle_sqla_session(self):
        assert type(myprogram_database.create_sqla_engine()) is # ?
```

How do I check the type of a variable that is a `class`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options here... The easiest is just to check that the object you get back is not `None`:

```
self.assertIsNotNone(myprogram_database.create_sqla_engine())
```

If you actually want to check that the return type is an instance of something else, you can use [`assertIsInstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance):

```
self.assertIsInstance(myprogram_database.create_sqla_engine(),
                      sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine)
```